# Using jQuery validation plugin to check an array called by a Google visualization api query

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, google-visualization

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin to check my student's ids when they log into class. Validating against an array using the following code works fine.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("studentID", function(value) {
 var ID = ['109289','109351'] /* Just a few Ids, but this works fine. */
 var in_array = $.inArray(value, ID);
 if (in_array == -1) {
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
    }}, "SORRY, NOT A VALID ID!"); $("#validID").validate({ success: function() { 
alert("It works!");} });
```

What I'm interested in doing is validating against an array which is called to an input field using google visualization api query each time the page loads. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to change the validation script to look at the input field's array of Ids. Is this even possible?

Here's a full [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MawWrX)

And here's the validation code with my (failed) attempt:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("studentID", function(value) {
var ID = document.getElementById("valIDS_out").value; /* Doesn't work??? */
var in_array = $.inArray(value, ID);
if (in_array == -1) {
    return false;
}else{
    return true;

}}, "SORRY, NOT A VALID ID!");

$("#validID").validate({ success: function() { 
alert("It works!");} });
```

Thanks for any assistance you can provide. I'm very new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `ID` variable is a string, not an array. You need to convert it to an array before calling `$.inArray()`.

If the string were formatted like the following:

```
"111111",222222","333333"
```

You could easily convert it to an array by using the `JSON.parse()` function:

```
var ID = JSON.parse('[' + document.getElementById("valIDS_out").value + ']');
```

But there are three things wrong with your string:

1. It contains single quotes, instead of double quotes. Unfortunately, `JSON.parse()` requires double quotes.
2. The first quote is missing.
3. There is an extra comma at the end.

That is, your string looks like this:

```
111111','222222','333333',
```

To correct all this, you could use:

```
var ID = JSON.parse('["' + document.getElementById("valIDS_out").value.slice(0,-1).replace(/\'/g, '"') + ']');
```

---

And you can shorten the next line to:

```
return ($.inArray(value, ID) >= 0);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng4L14ps/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution John, and taking the time to explain it. I'm always amazed by the willingness of experts in this community to help out newbies like me. I love learning this stuff. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As John S said, ID isn't an array, it's simply  a string, and it's not valid JSON which may be parsed.

Possible solution which works with the given String:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("studentID", function(value) {

  var ID = document.getElementById("valIDS_out").value;  

  return ((!isNaN(value) && ID.match(new RegExp('\\b'+value+'\\b'))));
}, "SORRY, NOT A VALID ID!");
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWPwdo

Comment: Thanks for your solution Dr. Molle. I appreciate how you demonstrated an alternative approach to the problem. I never would have thought of using a regular expression to match the ids.Terrific stuff!